# flutter run endless Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, gradlew, flutter-moor

I have a flutter project, that gets stuck on Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... if I execute the command "flutter run". It doesn't throw an error message or anything it just does nothing.
This happens only on my desktop pc. On my laptop everything works just fine.

Down below I will show you my flutter doctor -v output and my flutter run -v output but first I will tell you what I already did.

I reinstalled flutter and the android sdk.
I figured, that the project files are somehow damaged so I deleted the whole project and pulled it again from my git repository.

I created a new project with the default example app from flutter in it (You know the one where you can press a button and it tells you in the middle of the screen how many times you pushed it.)
That worked at first so I figured I messed it up while trying to integrate the moor_flutter package in my app. (I know that that isn't true because if I messed that up it wouldn't work on my laptop either but I am desperate.)

Anyways, I did the implementation step by step and ran the app after every change so I could check if I made a mistake.

1 step: add the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml

2 step: add set up the database and a test table.

3 step: initialized the database class

After every change I made I cleaned the flutter app, generated a new 'xxx.g.dart' file which is needed to use the moor_flutter package.
Everything worked.
Later that day after I got my motivation back I got back on my pc and tried to launch my test app again to figure out what I did wrong. I ran my test app and suddenly it won't get past "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..." anymore and I don't understand why because I didn't change anything.

I checked other posts of people who had the same problem and one suggested that its because the linux kernel 5.5.5-arch1-1 breaks gradlew somehow but I upgraded my laptop to check if that's true but it still works on my laptop.

flutter doctor -v output:

```html
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at
      /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (12 days ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /opt/android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/android-sdk
    • Java binary at:
      /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Mi MIX 2 • 78e7ab82 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

flutter run -v output:

```html
[  +16 ms] executing: [/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +4 ms] executing: [/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +31 ms] executing: [/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +75 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           78e7ab82               device usb:1-7 product:chiron model:Mi_MIX_2 device:chiron transport_id:3
[  +11 ms] /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 78e7ab82 shell getprop
[  +85 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +66 ms] Found plugin moor_ffi at
/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/moor_ffi-0.4.0/
[   +9 ms] Found plugin path_provider at
/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.1/
[  +57 ms] Found plugin moor_ffi at
/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/moor_ffi-0.4.0/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider at
/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.1/
[  +41 ms] Generating
/home/jan/development/projects/second_test_proj/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +28 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[  +30 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Mi MIX 2 in debug mode...
[   +7 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 78e7ab82 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +118 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 78e7ab82 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[   +1 ms] --------- beginning of main
           02-23 18:01:22.038 E/FIDOCA : (  752): get_fp_vendor property_get : none
[  +17 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[   +2 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 78e7ab82 logcat -v time -T 02-23 18:01:22.038
[  +41 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.6-6198805
           Installed as /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +1 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[   +6 ms] Building APK
[  +12 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +1 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +1 ms] Using gradle from /home/jan/development/projects/second_test_proj/android/gradlew.
[   +4 ms] executing: /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[  +36 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/jan/development/languages+devtools/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_202-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b49-5587405, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: [/home/jan/development/projects/second_test_proj/android/]
/home/jan/development/projects/second_test_proj/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget=/home/jan/development/projects/second_test_proj/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 assembleDebug
[+3436 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy and 9 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+6993 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[        ] [  +15 ms] executing: [/home/jan/development/languages+devtools/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[        ] [  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
```

Thanks for you help in advance.
Please excuse any spelling mistakes, English isn't my first language.
If you need more information just ask. :)

Comment: did you try: flutter clean or changing minSdkVersion from 16 to 21 ??

Comment: make sure that the kotlin compiler is set 1.8 target in android studio settings

Comment: @aligator Maybe I don't understand what you want me to do but in Android Settings/Plugins the latest Version is v.1.3.50 and under Android Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment Kotlin Compiler the latest version of "Language version" and "API version" is 1.3 aswell. The only field that I can set to 1.8 is "TargetJVM version" and that didn't work.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche sadly that did not work. Just out of curiosity why would it be sdk version 21. On the flutter homepage they say it must be at least 16.

Comment: @Jänner Check these links: [1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392), [2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47603). i think it has to do with your internet connection because it's downloading gradle.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche sadly this doesn't work either. I'm going to delete and reinstall everything from scratch. Maybe I'll figure out what went wrong and hopefully it works in the end. But thanks anyway I appreciate you help. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out myself after I tried to work on my app on my laptop.
At sunday night I could push the app from my laptop to my smartphone but yesterday at school I couldn't do anything anymore.
So I figured it must be my OS. I changed my linux kernel to the lts version and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

andoid studio->tools->flutter->open andoid module in studio

Try to run after you open just the android module. For me after i get the errors in the terminal.